# Java Apache POI ImageHeaderPNG missing

Tags: apache-tika

I am using latest dependency of Apache POI 4.1.2 in my java application together with Tika.
I realized that the class ImageHeaderPNG is missing with the following calls tack:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/sl/image/ImageHeaderPNG
    at org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Picture.fillImageContent(Picture.java:172)
    at org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Picture.getContent(Picture.java:279)
```

Inside Tika:

```
org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handlePictureCharacterRun(WordExtractor.java:560
  at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handleParagraph(WordExtractor.java:365)
  at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handleHeaderFooter(WordExtractor.java:257)
  at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.parse(WordExtractor.java:180)
  at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:175)
  at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:131)
  at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
  at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
  at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:143)
  at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:527)
  at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:602)
```

Any idea, hints where this class was moved to?

According to the online documentation it should be available:
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/sl/image/package-frame.html
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/sl/image/ImageHeaderPNG.html

Comment: Make sure you don't have any older copies of Apache POI on your classpath, error looks like you're accidentally using an old version of POI instead

Comment: I checked again my maven dependencies. You are right, I still had apache POI included. After removing it, the issue still can be seen with the same stack trace. Confirming with jar tf command I can see that the class is actually inside the JAR bundle. But still: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.sl.image.ImageHeaderPNG
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)